# Print horizontal with for in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have issues with python that i cant figure it out. I want to print a repetition of a word when the user enter a word and then he will tell how many times that word will repeat. I cant * by the way . Here code so far

```
b = raw_input 'enter word'
c = input 'enter the amount of time the word will repeat'

for g in range (c)
    print (b)
```

like you see you can see the repetition of the input but on vertical line, how I can print it horizontal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print in Python without newline or space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple. Just add comma.

```
print (b),
```

So your code becomes:

```
b = raw_input('enter word: ')
c = input('enter the amount of time the word will repeat: ')

for g in range (c):
    print b,
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it

```
import sys
b = raw_input('enter word')
c = input('enter the amount of time the word will repeat')

for g in range (c):
    sys.stdout.write(b)
```